# Save Doc as XML file

Tags: javascript, xml, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I`m new to coding and have an issue to create the XML file. The logic is: a website on Bubble.io platform sends POST request to Google Sheet, adds a new line and here the App Script starts working - it creates a new Google Doc based on the Doc Template I created, taking data from my Sheet. But I need to save it as XML file but not Doc. Is this actually possible?

I`m very thankful in advance for you help!

Here is my code in App Script:

```
function createSpreadsheetChangeTrigger() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('createNewGoogleDocs')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onChange()
      .create();
} 


function createNewGoogleDocs() {
  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('14fq85NxCIjOnwPoKIwo05tDXI15ThJlR8FS9rG9W6Go');
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1fNTFsBfjifUzdkkEfEN-r6ThrJtcQrQQ')
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName('sheet')
      const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();


        rows.forEach(function(row, index){
    if (index === 2) return;
    if (row[30]) return;


    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`${row[0]}, ${row[1]}` , destinationFolder)
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
    const body = doc.getBody();


        const friendlyDate = new Date(row[3]).toLocaleDateString();


    body.replaceText('{{CityCode}}', row[2]);
    body.replaceText('{{TaxReturnYear}}', row[3]);
    body.replaceText('{{NIFOfTaxpayerA}}', row[4]);
    body.replaceText('{{DegreeOfDisability}}', row[5]);
    body.replaceText('{{IfDisabledFromArmedForcesActivity}}', row[6]);


        doc.saveAndClose();  
    const url = doc.getUrl();
  sheet.getRange(index + 1, 31).setValue(url)
  
})



}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `But I need to save it as XML file but not Doc.`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect?

Comment: Hello! Sorry for my long answer. The first document it is what we have after auto-populating the template. As you can see, it has format .docx. And the second one what I need it to be, with .xml format. And I need to improve the code in AppScript in Google sheet, so that it saves in .xml format

Comment: Here is the link https://ru.files.fm/u/u2e6jzf8b

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to save the updated Google Document as an XML file.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
      doc.saveAndClose();  
  const url = doc.getUrl();
sheet.getRange(index + 1, 31).setValue(url)
```

#### To:

```
doc.saveAndClose();
const url = destinationFolder.createFile(`${doc.getName()}.xml`, body.getText(), "text/xml").getUrl(); // or application/xml
sheet.getRange(index + 1, 31).setValue(url);
// copy.setTrashed(true); // If you want to remove the template document, please use this line.
```

or, I think that the following modification might be able to be also used.

```
const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=${doc.getId()}&exportFormat=txt`, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } }).getBlob().setName(`${doc.getName()}.xml`).setContentType("text/xml"); // or application/xml
const url = destinationFolder.createFile(blob).getUrl(); // or application/xml
sheet.getRange(index + 1, 31).setValue(url);
// copy.setTrashed(true); // If you want to remove the template document, please use this line.
```

- When this modification is reflected in your showing script, the updated document is saved as an XML file to `destinationFolder`.
- If you are not required to add the extension of `.xml`. Please remove it from the above script.

#### References:

- [getText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#gettext)
- [createFile(name, content, mimeType)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createFile(String,String,String))